# Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MyService.Entities.Email'. The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller, metadata, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying out the new Visual Studio 11 Beta with MVC 4.0 and EF 4.3.1.

When adding a controller I get the following message "Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MyService.Entities.Email'. The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception"

Repro

I have a basic a solution which has an Entities project (MyService.Entities) and and MVC project (MyService.Website).

In the Entities project I have the bare bones for code first with a class for "Email" and a class for the DbContext. The two classes look like:
**EntitiesDb**

```
   namespace MyService.Entities
{
    public class EntitiesDb : DbContext
    {
        public EntitiesDb(string nameOrConnectionString)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        { }

        public EntitiesDb()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Sets up the defaults for the model builder
            // Removes the metadata being written to the database, This is being depreciated anyhow 
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

            // Sets the table names so that they are named as a none plural name 
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            // Creates the database from scratch when it builds
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Email**

```
namespace MyService.Entities
{
    public class Email
    {
        public Email()
        {
        }

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmailId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string BodyHTML { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have referenced the MyService.Entities project in the MyService.Website MVC project and set the Connection String to fit my Database name

```
<add name="EntitiesDb" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=EntitiesDb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I go to create the MVC scaffolding by doing the following:

- *Right click* on **Controllers** folder > **Add** > **Controller**
- Set controller name to be **EmailController**
- Set Template to **Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework**
- Set Model class to **Email(MyService.Entities)**
- Set Data context class to **EntitiesDb (MyService.Entities)**
- Set Views as **Razor**

It shows a message of

**"Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MyService.Entities.Email'. The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception"**

The confusing thing is that it worked initially and then I started to add some more entities and Properties into the database and then it wouldn't allow me. I've now scaled right back and it is still doing it.

I have tried a few things after looking on the forums:

- Checking the Connection string is correct in MVC Project Adding a
- Connection string in the Entities Project
- Reinstalled Visual Studio 11 Beta in case any updates have affected it
- Checking that the references match (they are both EntityFramework
  Version 4.3.1.0)
- Dropping the database to rebuild (Now I don't have one ;o))

Is this a bug in VS11? Am I missing a reference to the metadata somewhere?

Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT:
By un-installing the EntitiesFramework and re-installing the NuGet package fixed the problem.**

Comment: Did you check that the Version in your app.config (<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> matches the version of the Entity Framework you are referencing?

Comment: @Pawel. Thanks I have just checked that again and it was set as version 4.3.1.0. But it got me thinking so I uninstalled the NuGet package for EntityFramework on the MyService.Entities. When I did that it updated something in the Website Web.Config.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this section from webconfig

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,    EntityFramework" />
<providers>
 </providers>
</entityFramework>
```